# what is the meaning of object here in collections.sort?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, collections

what is the meaning of object o1,o2 here in collections.sort? and why he didn't write Process instead of object beacuse our list is based on process object

```
public static void sortremaning(ArrayList<Process> L) {
    Collections.sort(L, (Object o1, Object o2) -> {
        if (((Process) o1).getRemaningtime() == ((Process) o2).getRemaningtime()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (((Process) o1).getRemaningtime() < ((Process) o2).getRemaningtime()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not try it? Replace `Object` with `Process` and check if it works.

Answer (score 3):

When you turn to the javadoc for the [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method you find that it accepts `Comparator<? super T> c` as argument.

`Object` is a supertype of `Process` therefore the given example is correct java code.

Now: depending on your requirements, there might be a valid reason to actually work with a supertype, but not here: the given example could in fact use `Process` directly, which would allow to drop the type casts within the body of the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

`(Object o1, Object o2)` refer to the arguments of [`Comparator::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method, however, `Process` type should be used instead of Object to avoid redundant casting.

Also, depending on the type of `Process::getRemaningTime`, the body of the method may be reduced significantly.

Assuming `getRemaningTime` returns a long value, the code may be rewritten as:

```java
public static void sortremaning(ArrayList<Process> L) {
    Collections.sort(L, (p1, p2) -> Long.compareTo(p1.getRemaningTime(), p2.getRemaningTime()));
}

// or even simpler
public static void sortRemaning(ArrayList<Process> L) {
    Collections.sort(L, Comparator.comparingLong(Process::getRemaningTime));
}
```

In general case, the value returned by `getRemaningTime` should be of `Comparable` type, then the method can be updated as to use [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
public static void sortRemaning(List<Process> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Process::getRemaningTime));
}
```

Comment: …and then, `Collections.sort(list, …)` can be replaced by `list.sort(…)`